# My website is very overlapping and I don't know what to do

Tags: html, css, overlap, overlapping

I am trying to make a good website and I have a big problem: overlapping. 
When I make the window smaller, all of my elements are spread.
On mobile is worse. What can I do?
https://bucovina-tour.000webhostapp.com

Comment: Please note that the link you shared requires login/password (Or is the login screen the website itself? Because it looks fine on every screen size). Besides, welcome to StackOverflow. Try describing the expected behavior of your website and what have you tried so far, it really helps in understanding your problem.

Comment: The problem is in the welcome page, after login. I don't have so many eexperience in this domain. I searched on google and the single solve was to use index? Did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at your `.css` definitions, and it looks like the way you're positioning your html elements isn't ideal when trying to build a responsive/adaptative website.

When you define `margin-top: 500px` for your `.button_center` class, for example, please note that those margins will start stacking on top of each other at some point.

With standard resolution (1366x768, for example) there's enough space for all of your buttons to be inline with each other, so their margins will overlap and work as if they were one. When shrinking screen resolution, though, there won't be space for all of your buttons to stay in the same line, so they will start stacking on top of each other. But since, by `css` definition, there should be a margin of 500px on top of each button, they'll begin to spread vertically on the screen.

That's one of the reasons your website is overlapping, but there are a lot more. I highly recommend taking a look at [Responsive Webdesign Principles](https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/) and playing with responsivity on smaller scale before editing a template. When you stack multiple inexpected behaviors on CSS, it becomes exponentially difficult to understand **why** each element broke.

Also, explore the **inspect** tool that most browsers have. With this tool you might be able to visualize margins, borders, widths and various other characteristics of your html components simply by hovering over them! It's really useful for web debugging.

Answer (score 0):

- some of your code is very hard-coded. try to think about mobile sizes (and check it by console) before you give size to elements
- Like said above, for every step, use a @media query
- I strongly recommend learning how to work with flex in your CSS. It might seem a bit complicated at first, but it's really not. It does most of the responsive work for you. This is the real beauty of it!

Good luck :)